# Correct 'warranty' itemprop syntax

Tags: microdata, schema.org

What syntax is correct for `warranty` itemprop in https://schema.org/Offer?

This one

```html
<meta itemprop="warranty" content="2ANN" />
```

or …

```html
<meta itemprop="warranty" content="2 ANN" />
```

or with hierarchy …

```html
<span itemprop="warranty" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WarrantyPromise">
  <span itemprop="durationOfWarranty" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/QuantitativeValue">
    <span itemprop="value">2</span> years
    <meta itemprop="unitCode" content="ANN" />
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: For those wanting to know how to use with JSON-LD (instead of microdata), [I've posted it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41437038/usage-of-schema-orgs-warranty-with-json-ld-how-to-use-warranty-property/41437857#41437857).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`warranty` property](http://schema.org/warranty) expects a `WarrantyPromise` as value:

> **Values expected to be one of these types**
>   `WarrantyPromise`

So your last example is in line with Schema.org’s model.

(That doesn’t necessarily mean that consumers (e.g., search engines) would not also understand your first examples, but if you don’t have strong reasons against it you should go with the recommended approach.)