# Usage of schema.org's Warranty with JSON-LD / How to use Warranty property

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

*(This is a self-answered question. It wasn't posted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019537/correct-warranty-itemprop-syntax) since the user asked for microdata, not JSON-LD)*

How do you use the schema.org property "Warranty", listed in https://schema.org/warranty?.

There're no examples provided, not even for JSON-LD format. For instance, the article on *[`offers`](https://schema.org/offers)* provides examples like this:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "bestRating": "100",
    "ratingCount": "24",
    "ratingValue": "87"
  },
  "image": "dell-30in-lcd.jpg",
  "name": "Dell UltraSharp 30\" LCD Monitor",
  "offers": {
    "@type": "AggregateOffer",
    "highPrice": "$1495",
    "lowPrice": "$1250",
    "offerCount": "8",
    "offers": [
      {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "url": "save-a-lot-monitors.com/dell-30.html"
      },
      {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "url": "jondoe-gadgets.com/dell-30.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct usage is as follows (somewhere inside your HTML code):

*Tested on [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool. You can check it too](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool).*

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org/",
  "@type" : "Product",
  "name": "Sample product",
  "offers" : {
    "@type" : "Offer",
    "description": "Producto de Seiteka",
    "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
    "priceSpecification" : {
      "@type" : "PriceSpecification",
      "priceCurrency": "USD",
          "price": "45"
    },
    "warranty": {
      "@type": "WarrantyPromise",
      "durationOfWarranty" : {
        "@type" : "QuantitativeValue",
        "value": "6",
        "unitCode": "MON"
      },
      "warrantyScope": {
        "@type" : "WarrantyScope",
        "description": "Product listed in this page has 6 months of warranty."
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The organization [says the `warranty` property must be inside `Offer` or `Demand`, and that it should have WarrantyPromise inside](https://schema.org/warranty).

They also [say WarrantyPromise can have the properties `durationOfWarranty` and `warrantyScope`](https://schema.org/WarrantyPromise).

[For `durationOfWarranty` you must use `QuantitativeValue`](https://schema.org/durationOfWarranty), which [allows `value`](https://schema.org/QuantitativeValue) to be used.

[For `warrantyScope` you must use `WarrantyScope`](https://schema.org/warrantyScope), which [allows `description`](https://schema.org/WarrantyScope) to be used.

Finally, they talk something about [`warrantyPromise`](https://schema.org/warrantyPromise) (**not `WarrantyPromise`**) stating that `WarrantyPromise` property must be inside `warrantyPromise`.